# C# デスクトップの何もないところでのダブルクリックを拾いたい

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

ふと思いついて、こういうことはできるだろうかと思っての質問なのですが、
フォーム上ではなく、デスクトップの何もない場所でマウスのダブルクリックを
拾って処理をさせたいと思ったのですが、C#でその方法があればお教えください。

少しサイトで調べてみましたら、やはりAPIを使わないと無理だとかなんとか。
それならそれでも仕方ないのですが、もしできるのであれば、C#のみでできる方法、
不可能ならばAPIを絡めた方法をお願いします。

勿論、事前に非表示のC#で組んだプログラムが常駐のような形で動いているものとしてです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 何も無い部分ということなら透明な全画面ウインドウを最前面にしてダブルクリックを拾ってみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、今になってコメントに気がつきました。
透明なウインドウを配置してしまうと、今度は普通のデスクトップ上の
アイコンを操作できません。また、透明化すると結局透明部分はデスクトップを
ダブルクリックすることになってしまうので、結果は同じです。そのため、
デスクトップでのダブルクリックをとらえたかったのですが…、無理にやろうと
するよりは、やらない方が良いようでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

デスクトップと言えど単なるウィンドウです。ウィンドウメッセージは`WindowProc`で処理されますが、これは[SetWindowLongPtr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx)を使うことでフックすることはできますが

> An application can subclass a system class, but should not subclass a window class created by another process.

と記載されており外部からフックすべきではありません。
それとは別に[SetWindowsHookEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx)を使うことで外部からフックすることはできますが、[How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/kb/318804)でも

> Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework

と説明されているようにC#では実現できません。C/C++を使用したネイティブのDLLを作成する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
いつもすみません。

やはり単体ではできませんでしたか。
それにやるべきではないということであれば、無理に
やらない方がよいのかもしれません。

この課題はあきらめることにします。